# ShapeRenderer colors stop working when rendering images with SpriteBatch

Tags: android, colors, drawing, sprite, libgdx

I've made a game that uses `ShapeRenderer` for making colorized lines. This worked fine, but when I start to import images the colored lines suddenly became black. Worst of all: When I'm using a background the lines doesn't show at all, and yes, i'm drawing it in the right order....

Code for importing and rendering the images:

```
Constructor(){
    TextureAtlas atlas = new TextureAtlas(Gdx.files.internal("data/texture.atlas"));
    AtlasRegion region = atlas.findRegion("path");
    Sprite sprite = new Sprite(region);
}
```

..........................................

```
@Override
public void render() {
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(255, 255, 255, 1);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    batch.begin();
    background.draw(batch); // drawing the background

    drawing.draw(); // drawing the lines
    drawObjects(); // drawing some pictures
    batch.end();
}
```

But when I remove the code for rnedering the background and the pictures the lines will show up and in the right color....

Please help!!

EDIT: Drawing with the `ShapeRenderer` looks something like this (Don't have to put everything in):

```
public void draw() {
    shaperenderer.begin(ShapeType.Line);
    shaperenderer.setColor(Color.RED);
    shaperenderer.line(1, 1, 100, 100);
    shaperenderer.end();
}
```

Comment: Does `drawObjects()` invoke `ShapeRenderer.begin()`?  Since your question is about `ShapeRenderer` it would be useful to include the code that invokes it ...

Comment: Ok, I can edit that in. But notice that it works fine if I just remove the images!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You cannot nest objects that depend on OpenGL context.  Specifically, you are nesting a `ShapeRenderer.begin()` within a `SpriteBatch.begin()`.  If you change render to look like this:

```
batch.begin();
background.draw(batch); // drawing the background
batch.end(); // end spritebatch context to let ShapeRenderer in

drawing.draw(); // drawing the lines (with ShapeRenderer)

batch.begin(); 
drawObjects(); // drawing some pictures
batch.end();
```